# Wrapping a function within another

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am working on taking two divs, having them hidden on page load but having each drop down separately when one is clicked on. When one is active the other is hidden.

So far I have

```
$( '#div, #div1' ).hide(); {
$( "#div" ).click(function() {
$( "#div1" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});
```

But I am having trouble wrapping the click function within the initial one. The divs are being called by a picklist.

Can someone walk me through this? I would prefer a step by step example. I have very limited experience in writing jQuery and appreciate the help.

Here is the page link to which I am working on.

https://www.gdg.do/prod1/portal/portal.jsp?c=6696885&p=8296647&g=8297605

What I'm wanting to do, I want both 'Group' areas hidden on page load. Then once a selection is made in the drop down, the corresponding 'Group' slides down. When the other 'Group' is selected the first one disappears and the newly selected one is visible.

I hope that is clearer.

Comment: Where are your functions?

Comment: please add it to the question, not the comments

Comment: If they are truly hidden, as in 'display: none', then you can't click them.  Are you thinking more along the lines of a collapsible?  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $sliderDivs = $( '#div, #div1' );
$sliderDivs.click(function(e){
    $(this).slideDown("slow");
    $sliderDivs.not(this).slideUp( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}
```

All jQuery event handlers set the context(what `this` is set to) to the element that fired the event.

The reason for saving a selector as a $-prefixed variable is that it is easier to maintain(changes only have to be made in one place), and it is faster(jquery traverses the dom every time you wrap a selector with $() )

**EDIT:** Against my better judgement I made you a quick example:

http://codepen.io/tpblanke/pen/hrlgL

Should get you where you need to be.

Comment: I edited the original question to more definitively ask the question.

Comment: @CCanada I edited the post to more directly show how to accomplish what you are trying to do. Should work with some minor tweaking.

Comment: Can you show me a fiddle/example of this working please?

Comment: @CCanada That would deny you a valuable chance to learn. If you have any questions, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: That was why I asked so I could see the changes that were made and compare them. I'm not asking for someone to do it for me just to walk me through each step as I am very new to this.
But thanks regardless.

Comment: @CCanada See my edit. It should give you a good base to build on. If so, please select this as an accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Thad Blankenship. I really appreciate it.